# Jasmine throws "can't find variable: require"

Tags: typescript, gulp, jasmine, commonjs

I have a VS2015 TypeScript project transpiling to ECMA5 using the CommonJS module system, and unit-tests with Jasmine on the same project. Some of the code references `self` so I need to run the tests with jasmineBrowser to have a browser-like environment.

I tried running the tests with `jasmineBrowser.server`, but after the "Jasmine server listening" message it keeps hanging. I tried switching to `jasmineBrowser.headless` using PhantomJS 2 as instructed on the gulp-jasmine-browser documentation, but then I get this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

It is of no importance for me whether the tests will run using `jasmineBrowser.server` or `jasmineBrowser.headless`. Any solution works for me. Some code is pasted below.

Spec file:

```
import {MockHub} from "path/to/mockHub";
import {Subject} from "path/to/Subject";

describe("A nice little test", () => {
    let mockHub: MockHub;
    let subject: Subject;    

    jasmine.getEnv().updateInterval = 200;
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 60000;

    beforeEach(function () {
        mockHub = new MockHub();
        subject = new Subject();
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        mockHub.dispose();
    });

    it("should assert that it works", function () {
        let result = -1,
            done = false;

        mockHub.bind(someEvent, () => {
            result = subject.getResult();
            done = true;
        });

        runs(function () {
            setTimeout(() => mockHub.dispatch(someEvent), 2000);
        });

        waitsFor(function () {
            return done;
        });

        runs(function () {
            expect(result).toEqual(0);
        });
    });
});
```

Gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine'),
    runSequence = require("run-sequence"),
    jasmineBrowser = require('gulp-jasmine-browser');

gulp.task("test", function () {
    gulp.src([
        "tests/**/SubjectSpec.js"
    ])
    .pipe(jasmineBrowser.specRunner({ console: true }))
    .pipe(jasmineBrowser.headless());
    // .pipe(jasmineBrowser.specRunner({ console: true }))
    // .pipe(jasmineBrowser.server({port: 9000}));

});
```

Subject.js file, transpiled from Subject.ts file:

```
import {EventTypes} from "./EventTypes";

class Subject implements ISubject {
    let counter = 0;

    constructor(private hub: IHub) {
        this.hub.bind(EventTypes.all, () => this.counter++);
    }

    public getResult(): number {
        return this.counter;
    }
}

export {Subject};
```